# Convert ArrayOfStrings to String[] in JAVA when consuming .NET webservice

Tags: java, .net, arrays, web-services, list

In JAVA I am consuming (JAX-WS client) .NET webservice that returns data of type **string[]**.

After I consume web service In JAVA, I get object ArrayOfStrings, and I don't have idea what to do with it. This class is generated by wsimport tool.

**I need somehow to convert it to String[]**

I tried to change web service to return List, but in java, resulting data is always of type ArrayOfStrings.

Is there a way to receive List or Array in JAVA?

.NET

```
    [WebMethod]
    public List<string> GetListADocuments(string code)
    { ... }
```

JAVA:

```
    WebServiceSoap service = client.getWebServiceSoap();
    result = service.getListADocuments(code);
```

Thanks

Comment: Please stop shouting Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't it have a method result.getString()? that return a String[] or List

Comment: Uh, there is method getString() available. It returns the List<String>. Somehow I refused to notice it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get its length, make a String[] the same length, iterate over ArrayOfStrings' contents, fill String[] with it. If ArrayOfStrings' has any methods that return a String[] directly, of course use that instead.